# How to find max value in array of dictionary

Tags: python

I have this array:

```
[{
    'name': 'Chrysanthemum.jpg',
    'number': 100.0
  }, {
    'name': 'Desert.jpg',
    'number': 30.917470438414448
  }, {
    'name': 'Hydrangeas.jpg',
    'number': 15.429520638195438
  },
  {
    'name': 'Jellyfish.jpg',
    'number': 21.331146972809318
  }, {
    'name': 'Koala.jpg',
    'number': 20.341379328776572
  }, {
    'name': 'Lighthouse.jpg',
    'number': 34.424389703830229
  }, {
    'name': 'Penguins.jpg',
    'number': 25.732106503594785
  }, {
    'name': 'Tulips.jpg ',
    'number': 23.827037756867568}]
```

Now I want to find a item which its number is max. any idea?

Comment: And what would the expected output be? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a custom key using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) for fetching the number

```
from operator import itemgetter
max_item = max(l, key=itemgetter('number'))
print(max_item)
```

**Outputs**:

```
{'name': 'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 'number': 100.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max(d['number'] for d in Array_dict)
```

output :

```
100.0
```

if item :

```
max(Array_dict, key=lambda x:x['number'])
```

output :

```
{'name': 'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 'number': 100.0}
```

Comment: They want the item (dictionary) with the highest `'number'` value, not just the highest value.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary will be regularly structured like you've shown above, then this should be a simple way of achieving what you need:

`max(d['number'] for d in dictionary_list)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dd = [{'name': 'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 'number': 100.0}, {'name': 'Desert.jpg', 'number' : 30.917470438414448}, {'name': 'Hydrangeas.jpg', 'number': 15.429520638195438},  {'name': 'Jellyfish.jpg', 'number': 21.331146972809318}, {'name': 'Koala.jpg', 'number': 20.341379328776572}, {'name': 'Lighthouse.jpg', 'number': 34.424389703830229}, {'name': 'Penguins.jpg', 'number': 25.732106503594785}, {'name': 'Tulips.jpg', 'number': 23.827037756867568}]
lst = []
[lst.append(l.values()[1]) for l in dd]
max_no = max(lst)

for item in dd:
  if item['number'] == max_no:
    print item
    break
```